# Discord bot python choice color in embed

Tags: python

Olá, estou tendo um problema, tento escolher uma cor, e não vai, mas já o titulo, description vai, alguem pode me dizer o certo para fazer para pegar as cores?

```
laranjavermelho = 0xFF4500
laranja = 0xFFA500
amarelo = 0xFFFF00
branco = 0xFFFAFA
brancofantasma = 0xF8F8FF

listacores = laranjavermelho, laranja, amarelo,branco, brancofantasma

@client.command(
    description="Crie embeds legais",
    brief="Crie Embed")
async def embed(ctx, title : str, description : str, cores : listacores):

    embed=discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, colour = cores)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: Muito provavelmente você quer fazer isso: `listacores = [laranjavermelho, laranja, amarelo,branco, brancofantasma]`. (Não tenho experiência com a API do Discord).

Comment: não funcionou, mas obrigado

Answer (score 1):

Tenho alguma experiência de construção de bots no Discord em outras linguagens (C# e JS). Para "Embed Messages", pela minha experiência com a plataforma do Discord, acredito que **apenas uma cor pode ser passada**:

```
embed = discord.Embed(title=title, description=description, colour=cores[0])
```

Imagino que não receba várias cores no construtor de uma "Embed Message", é um comportamento que nunca vi no Discord e em nenhuma outra API.

Espero ter ajudado de alguma forma.